# Calling a nested function with a string (window[]) in JS

Tags: javascript, string, nested-function

How to call a nested function with only a string? eg:

```
function oot(wha)   {
        function inn(wha)
          {
          First.innerHTML+="Inner ["+wha+"]";
          }
   oot.inn = inn;
   Second.innerHTML+="Outer ["+wha+"]";
                    }
 oot("1");  
 oot.inn("2");  //works okay
 window["oot"]("3");    //works okay
 window["oot.inn"]("4");    //<The problem, doesn't work.
 window["oot"]["inn"]("4");  //Works, thanks.
```

Edited to make the code more readable, and show a solution.

IF there is no way to make this work with a single string i can probably make do, but i will leave the question unanswered for a few hours to see if there is another solution.

Comment: Could you indent your code properly?

Comment: `oot.inn` is not a property of the global object. Should be `window.oot.inn` or `window["oot"]["inn"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference nested Objects like this:

```
window["oot"]["inn"]("4");
```

or

```
window.oot.inn("4")
```

Comment: They can, but the problem is that they have the string `oot.inn` and need to transform it to that.